# How to know when dataproc initialization actions are done

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I need to run a `Dataproc` cluster with both BigQuery and Cloud Storage connectors installed.

I use a variant of [this script](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/connectors) (because I have no access to the bucket used in the general one), everything is working fine but when I run a job, when the cluster is up and running, it always results in a `Task was not acquired` error.

I can fix this by simply restarting the dataproc agent on every nodes but I really need this to work properly to be able to run a job right after my cluster is created. it seems that this part of the script is not working properly:

```
# Restarts Dataproc Agent after successful initialization
# WARNING: this function relies on undocumented and not officially supported Dataproc Agent
# "sentinel" files to determine successful Agent initialization and not guaranteed
# to work in the future. Use at your own risk!
restart_dataproc_agent() {
  # Because Dataproc Agent should be restarted after initialization, we need to wait until
  # it will create a sentinel file that signals initialization competition (success or failure)
  while [[ ! -f /var/lib/google/dataproc/has_run_before ]]; do
    sleep 1
  done
  # If Dataproc Agent didn't create a sentinel file that signals initialization
  # failure then it means that initialization succeded and it should be restarted
  if [[ ! -f /var/lib/google/dataproc/has_failed_before ]]; then
    service google-dataproc-agent restart
  fi
}
export -f restart_dataproc_agent

# Schedule asynchronous Dataproc Agent restart so it will use updated connectors.
# It could not be restarted sycnhronously because Dataproc Agent should be restarted
# after its initialization, including init actions execution, has been completed.
bash -c restart_dataproc_agent & disown
```

My question here are:

1. How to know that the initialization actions are done?
2. Do I have/How to properly restart the Dataproc agent one my newly created cluster's nodes?

**EDIT:**
Here is the command I use to create a cluster (using the 1.3 image version):

```
gcloud dataproc --region europe-west1 \
  clusters create my-cluster \
  --bucket my-bucket \
  --subnet default \
  --zone europe-west1-b \
  --master-machine-type n1-standard-1 \
  --master-boot-disk-size 50 \
  --num-workers 2 \
  --worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
  --worker-boot-disk-size 100 \
  --image-version 1.3 \
  --scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' \
  --project my-project \
  --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/connectors/connectors.sh \
  --metadata 'gcs-connector-version=1.9.6' \
  --metadata 'bigquery-connector-version=0.13.6'
```

Also, please note that the connectors initialization script has been fixed and works fine by now, so I am using it now but I still have to restart manually the dataproc agent to be able to run a job.

Comment: May you share command how you create cluster and what Dataproc image version do you use (with subminor version, i.e. 1.x.x)?

Comment: Sure, I edit the question with the requested info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Dataproc agent logs `Custom initialization actions finished.` message in the `/var/log/google-dataproc-agent.0.log` file after initialization actions succeed.
2. No you don't need to restart Dataproc agent manually.

This issue is caused by [Dataproc agent service restart in the connectors initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/1199525c18e7f67bce89dd58d0887ea00354807b/connectors/connectors.sh#L91) and should be resolved by [this PR](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/pull/341).

Answer (score 0):

As for knowing when the initialization actions are finished, You can check the dataproc's `status.state`, if it's `CREATING` that means initialization actions are still being executed, if `RUNNING` that would mean that they are done!
Check [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/list)